# Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null When merging json objects using Object.assign

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, redux

Hi In my reducer I'm merging two objects using "Object.assign" and I'm getting a TypeError. I have simplified the code for understanding purpose

Inside Reducer

```
case "UPDATE_ITEMS":
    let state = {title:'', id:''};
    let action = {assignmentItemList: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']};
    let newObj = Object.assign({}, state, {assignmentItemList: action.assignmentItemList});

    return newObj;
```

In action file.

```
export function getItemListSuccess (assignmentItemList) {
    return {type: types.GET_ASSIGNMENT_ITEM_LIST_SUCCESS, assignmentItemList};
}
```

Inside thunk

```
//doing http call using fetch
try {
    dispatch(getItemListSuccess(response.items));
} catch(ex) {
    console.log(ex);
}
```

I'm getting following as the response.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of null
    at t.value (bundle.js:12)
    at r.notifyAll (react.min.js:12)
    at r.close (react.min.js:15)
    at r.closeAll (react.min.js:16)
    at r.perform (react.min.js:16)
    at o.perform (react.min.js:16)
    at o.perform (react.min.js:15)
    at Object.N [as flushBatchedUpdates] (react.min.js:15)
    at r.closeAll (react.min.js:16)
    at r.perform (react.min.js:16)
```

I want to know why this error is happening ?

Comment: *"I have simplified the code for understanding purpose"* - I think you've over-simplified, because the code shown doesn't give an error. Note that the code shown doesn't copy the array, it just copies a reference to the array. Also, there's no JSON in this question, just objects and arrays.

Comment: Problem is edited now.